# Optimizing the speed of an algorithm that determines the occurence and lenght of consecutive white pixels in an image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Currently I am writing a piece of code that determines the location and lenght of consecutive white pixels sequences for each pixel-line in an image. The image only contains black and white pixels.

The code looks as follows:

```
    totalSeq = []
    for pixelLine in threshImg:
        pixelLineSeq = []  
        seq = []
        for i, pixel in enumerate(pixelLine):
            if pixel == 255:
                seq.append(i)
            if pixel != 255:
                pixelLineSeq.append(seq)
                seq = []
        pixelLineSeq.append(seq) # append last found sequence
        totalSeq.append(pixelLineSeq)
```

To elaborate on the above. The code loops over each pixel line/row in the image. For each line a list (pixeLineSeq) is created that will contain the lists that represent the location of consecutive white pixel values for that corresponding pixel line.

Afterwards the sequences are painted red if the length of the sequence is greater than a given minimum length.

```
def callback(minLength):
    imgMask = img.copy() 
    for line, lineM in zip(totalSeq, imgMask):
        for seq in line:
            if len(seq) > minLength:
                lineM[seq] = [0, 0, 255]
    cv.imshow(source_window, imgMask)
```

Now the code works fine but is rather slow for larger images. The first double for loop in the first block of code is especially tedious here. Does anybody know how I can eliminate this double for loop in order to speed up the process?

Comment: numpy. `np.diff` and `np.nonzero` are useful building blocks. there's no reason to touch individual pixels or to loop over them. that's wasteful and requires needless code.

Comment: These two methods look very promising! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to count the number of adjacent pixels, why not use a counter, instead of appending to a list? That would be somewhat faster and would consume less memory overall:

```py
maxLength = 0

for pixelLine in threshImg:
    seqLength = 0

    for i, pixel in enumerate(pixelLine):
        if pixel == 255:
            seqLength = seqLength + 1
        else:
            if maxLength < seqLength:
                maxLength = seqLength

            seqLength = 0

    if maxLength < seqLength:
        maxLength = seqLength
```

The above code is untested, but you get the main idea.

Please, keep in mind that Python is inherently slow for such computationally intensive tasks. Even with my 'optimization', I would expect the above code to be relatively slow. Typically, such image processing in Python is performed via a library written in C/C++ to get optimal performance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ivan, I also need to know the location of the white pixels that are adjacent to each other. But your comment give me an idea!